# One complex wildcard query lead solr OOM

Tags: search, solr, lucene

We are using Solr as our search engine, and recently notice some user input wildcard query can lead to Solr dead loop in

```
org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.Operations.determinize()
```

And it also eats memory and finally OOM.

the wildcard query seems like `*?????????-???????o·???è??*`。

Although we can validate the input parameter, but I also wonder is there any configuration which can disable complex wildcard query like this which lead to serve performance problems.

Comment: Do you want to be able to perform wildcard queries at all? Otherwise you can just escape the input properly.

Comment: Hi Mats, yes, escaping the input solving this problem, but the question is "is there some configuration which can limit how complex the query is".

Comment: No that I know of - but you can add a max running time for a query (`timeAllowed`).